Are there any ways to improve handling of the insufficient_quota error while using spring-ai?
I am following the OpenAI Chat tutorial from Spring AI: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ai/reference/api/clients/openai-chat.html#_sample_controller_auto_configuration
As soon as I started the service, I noticed the following errors in the service log, while my requests seemed "hanging".
org.springframework.ai.retry.NonTransientAiException: 429 - {
    "error": {
        "message": "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.",
        "type": "insufficient_quota",
        "param": null,
        "code": "insufficient_quota"
    }
}

The above is an expected outcome since I don't have $$$ on the account.
BUT, I wonder are there better ways to handle the insufficient_quota error from the other ones? As an example, I want to fail fast if there is such an error and keep retrying with default policies for any other errors.
Or, do I need to use my custom RetryTemplate in this case?
BTW, I've tried to set the following property, but it seems it doesn't take any effect...
spring.ai.retry.exclude-on-http-codes=429


I faced a similar challenge while working on a project,Handle the insufficient_quota, by visiting the OpenAI https://platform.openai.com/settings/organization/billing/overview
and update the billing details.

The question was about my requests seemed "hanging"... I want to fail fast if there is such an error, so that the system can respond quickly, or try an alternative approach to get information. Does updating billing significantly reduce the response time?
